# nodejs mustache/handlebars example project

Tags: node.js, less, mustache

I've been looking to use mustache or handlebars and nodejs but I have't been successful to finding a sample project online that is working.

I just need a sample skeleton structure which uses mustache as a templating engine.

My goal is to use nodejs, mustache/handlebars, less (css framework) and some good routing but haven't been able to find a good example to work off.

## UPDATE

I created a project which uses less, mustache and express using some tutorial online but I'm getting an error at startup. app.js at https://gist.github.com/1237758

I'm getting TypeError: Object # has no method 'compile'

I have express, less and mustache in my node_modules.

Comment: I copied your app.js to a new project, ran "npm install express mustache less" and then "node app.js" and it replied with "Express server listening on port 3000 in development mode".

Comment: Edit box timed out on me... my versions are node@0.4.7, express@2.4.6, mustache@0.3.1-dev and less@1.1.4

Comment: Yes I get that message too but when I open the url in browser, it gives me the error. I have the same exact versions as you except for less@1.1.3

Comment: I have created an example project with node & mustache working. See my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

> http://bitdrift.com/post/2376383378/using-mustache-templates-in-express

Comment: Note that this is outdated by now: Express no longer supports partials, instead each template has to manage this on its own now

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [stache](https://github.com/fat/stache) module. It makes it much easier to use mustache in express. Check out the examples.

Comment: npm install stache doesn't add stache to the node_modules. It doesn't do anything.

Comment: I just checked, and it does. But if npm install doesn't work for you though you can always just clone the git repo.

Comment: there is an example on stache'e git repo but that  doesn't come with npm module. it just has the stache.js

Comment: I've created a complete example with node & mustache - see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The source of your error seems to reside in `connect` module, `connect/lib/middleware/compiler.js` but I can't reproduce the error. It is possible that you have an old connect module inside your $NODE_PATH

Comment: How do I check the version of the connect module?

Comment: using `node`: `var c = require('connect'); console.log(c.version);`

Comment: watching again your code, seems that Mike Swift had the right answer. Express doesn't supports mustache right out of the box. By the way, you should paste the full backtrace, the `compile` function is indeed related to express's render module. (I commented your gist with my error backtrace)

Answer (score 0):

As you have already received some answers with regard to templating I thought I would answer the routing one. Try out http://sammyjs.org/ a small web framework written in js.

Also there are some examples https://github.com/quirkey/sammy/tree/master/examples/

Answer (score 0):

I looked for a Express/Handlebars/Less framework, but couldn't find any templates that I was satisfied with.

I ended up making my own Express/Handlebars/Less project template on GitHub:

[Express-Handlebars-Less-Jasmine-NodeUnit_Project-Template](https://github.com/Dibbin/Express-Handlebars-Less-Jasmine-NodeUnit_Project-Template)